# Python Regex Matching Too Much

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Regex101 Tester: https://regex101.com/r/Yfp311/2

I am having difficulty getting the following regex pattern to work. For the sample text strings below, REF1 is matched for the entire line, ignoring the *optional* REF2 group that should be matched if the "//[text]" is found in line.

At the moment, regex is not acknowledging the //[text] and incorrectly matching the entire text as REF1. I am assuming this is a characteristic of greedy matching .. however I was unsuccessful at implementing a non-greedy pattern, and also lookahead/lookbehind (did not appear to work) either.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated ... not sure what I am missing as I would think my current regex pattern should work without issue. Please let me know if I can clarify anything! Thank you!

```
^(?P<ID>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3})?(?P<REF1>.+)(//(?P<REF2>.+))?(\n?(?P<EXTRA>.+))?$
```

---

```
TEX1CNS0P5-AA//CAT-523-VID-00EOS-0
XUX PETER LAB RANDOM TEXT DM5.

TEX2BFTBSH9999SBRT2L
RATRACE201

TEX3GWS0P2-AA//D-14839048-99-3
THERE WAS 200 COALS IN HIS STOCKING.
```

**Expected Matches:**

- String 1:

  - id: TEX1
  - ref1: CNS0P5-AA
  - ref2: CAT-523-VID-00EOS-0
  - extra: XUX PETER LAB RANDOM TEXT DM5.
- String 2:

  - id: TEX2
  - ref1: BFTBSH9999SBRT2L
  - ref2: (no match, since "//" does not appear in this text)
  - extra: RATRACE201
- String 3:

  - id: TEX3
  - ref1: GWS0P2-AA
  - ref2: D-14839048-99-3
  - extra: THERE WAS 200 COALS IN HIS STOCKING.

Comment: It's much easier for readers if you begin your question with a statement of what you are trying to do, without reference to code, then given one or more examples for illustration (if needed), for each showing the desired result. Only then introduce code that is in need of repair.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you, I will try to be more concise in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`^(?P<ID>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3})?(?P<REF1>[^/\n]+)(//(?P<REF2>.+))?(\n?(?P<EXTRA>.+))?$`

I have updated it. I guess it passes the required cases now:

https://regex101.com/r/Yfp311/3

The issue with the original implementation is `REF1` matches everything apart from line terminators. So it matched `//` as well.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much! So by including (?P<REF1>[^/\n]+), it looks to not match against those characters, and effectively matches correctly!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
^(?P<ID>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3})?(?P<REF1>[^/\n]+)(//(?P<REF2>.+))?(\n?(?P<EXTRA>.+))?$
```

?

I think a hand-written parser is more achievable in this case.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you would recommend a hand-written parser? For what benefit so I may understand? P.S the new regex works great! Could you please explain what was wrong/missing in mine?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering a more ideal answer, as the provided regex patterns fail when REF1 text contains a single "/" forward slash.

```
^(?P<ID>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3})?(?P<REF1>(?:(?!//).)+)(//(?P<REF2>.+))?(\n?(?P<EXTRA>.+))?$
```

For Example - https://regex101.com/r/Yfp311/4

```
TEX4POF OF 20/03/09//CAT342134832489
P/O:1600 PARK AVENUE
```

Using a negative lookahead regex pattern helped resolved this gap.